# laravel eloquent nested relationship count

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested, relationship

i have 4 database tables :

Broadcasters
| id | public_name | .... |

Articles
| id | title| .... |

Comments
| id | user_id| article_id | .... |

users
| id | login| .... |

i would like to list all broadcasters with number of article of each one (broadcaster) and the totale comments  of all article ( of the broadcaster ). below my code that i make but it miss samething

```
Broadcaster::withCount(['articles'])
                             ->withCount(['articles'=> function($query){
                                return $query->withCount("comments");
                             }])

                             ->get();
```

i checked in stackoverflow forum but didnot get any answer of my question , please help and thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a relation **hasManyThrough** in Broadcasters class:

```
function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Comment', 'App\Articles');
}
```

So you can

```
Broadcaster::withCount(['articles','comments'])
```

[Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)